# How long to cook stuffed turkey

Tags: turkey

What is the cooking time for a stuffed turkey at 350 degrees? 
I read that it should be 20 minutes per pound, is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how long to cook a turkey per pound](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/how-long-to-cook-a-turkey-per-pound)

Comment: I'm leaning toward not saying this is a duplicate, because while the answer is still "use a thermometer" it's a little different when there's stuffing.

Comment: I have voted to leave this question open for 2 reasons: 1) This is about a stuffed turkey. 2) The answers to the existing question isn't particularly useful for planning the turkey dinner, which I think most people are trying to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Stick a thermometer in the stuffing; when the stuffing is at 160F, you're done. Since heat radiates inwards from the outside, you don't want the very middle of the dish (where the stuffing is) to be any colder than needed to kill salmonella. Estimate a bit longer than an unstuffed turkey.

Comment: And of course, keep in mind that by the time the stuffing is that hot, the turkey will be overcooked. This is why a lot of people say not to bother putting stuffing in the turkey, or to do it after both are cooked.

Comment: You could also heat the stuffing separately (microwave?) then shove it into the raw turkey and roast as planned. The stuffing would cool some while the turkey heated, but it might be safer than waiting for cold stuffing inside a cold turkey to come up to temp.

Answer (score 0):

Turkey is done when the internal temperature reaches 160&deg F.  That's the temperature required to kill the bad stuff; so any cooking for any longer just dries out your turkey unnecessarily.

However, getting to this temperature varies depending on a lot of factors like your oven, the turkey's construction, and the exact phase of the moon. (Just kidding about the moon - kinda.)

The generally accepted formula for estimating cook time at a standard 350° F bake is 20 minutes per pound of turkey + another 20 minutes. Thus, an 11 pound turkey would reach 160&deg F in about 4 hours.  (Note that this is for a truly fully defrosted turkey.)

If you're doing a traditional "shoved into the raw turkey cavity" thing, add another 20 - 30 minutes to get the stuffing up to the 160&deg F. temperature.  Since the stuffing is put into the raw cavity, it's likely to absorb raw turkey juices, which must be brought up to the same safe temperature.